# Determine potential duplicates in string or array

Tags: php

I am parsing RSS feeds with PHP into a MySQL database. Before inserting the new entry in the DB I would like to check (by comparing the titles of the items) if there is already a similar entry in the MySQL database available and flag them accordingly. Now I don't know how to determine that the candidates in the listed example are potential duplicates of the source.

**Example:**

source:

- CES: Panasonic und Technisat neu in der Smart TV Alliance

candidates:

- Panasonic, IBM, Specific Media, ABOX42 und TechniSat ... - Area DVD
- CES 2013: Panasonic, IBM, Specific Media, ABOX42 und TechniSat ...
- Panasonic ABOX42 IBM Specific Media and TechniSat ExpandBuild Once ...
- Panasonic, IBM, Specific Media, ABOX42 und TechniSat erweitern die ...
- ...

Already tried array_intersect and levenshtein(), but the results are not very accurate. If have no idea any more.

Best, Andreas

Comment: All of your candidates seem quite different from the source, plus they are in different languages. Most comparison algorithms take language into consideration. More general or different algorithms are available (such as the ones in Solr), but they are not available directly in PHP as simple functions. You may  need to build an external service (e.g. in Java) which is called by PHP.

Comment: I see. There will might be no "simple" solution for that problem. Many thanks for you reply.

Comment: See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Phonetic_algorithms, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone (PHP implementation: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking aloud and giving a few pointers:

- Remove everything but numbers, letters, and white space

  ```
  $title = preg_replace('/[^\w\d ]+/', '', $title);
  ```
- Explode into an array

  ```
  $parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $title);
  ```
- You can now optionally count repeated words: `array_count`
- Finally you can compare the resulting arrays with each other and check for duplicates with, say, 80 % likeliness (80 % of the array items match)

Comment: Many thanks for your idea sharing. But how should I handle conjunctions like "and", "because", ... This words will cause a inaccurate comparison result.

Comment: Well, you could create an array containing stop-words, which acts as a blacklist. Use array_filter or array_diff to strip them from the array